# How can I get the secret achievements?

Tags: steam, achievements, bleed

There are seven secret achievements for the Steam edition of *Bleed*. There is one for each stage in the game, and they are listed as *Secret Mission 01* through *Secret Mission 07*.

What are the requirements for each of them?

Comment: I only really need #4 at this point, but it would be good to have a comprehensive list here.

Comment: They are there so you can unlock them.. Seriously, whats this question?

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness [The secret achievements have no text to tell you how to get them.](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/239800/achievements)  Ktash has helpfully edited the title to eliminate the misunderstanding.

Comment: The edit made it much more clear.

Comment: Yeah, my bad guys, although next time you should read the body text first.

Comment: If Achievements are hidden, just have a look on AStats.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness Good idea, but since the game is fairly new to steam, there's no results for it yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Secret Mission 01: Gate Crasher** (Stage 1)

[image: Gate Crasher]

Awarded for smashing all of the chandeliers in Guppy's Mansion

---

**Secret Mission 02: Anti-Omelette** (Stage 2)

[image: Anti-Omelette]

Awarded for not breaking any of the eggs in the Lava Caves

---

**Secret Mission 03: Lil' Mama** (Stage 3)

[image: Lil' Mama]

Awarded for not tripping any of the lasers in the High Security Complex

---

**Secret Mission 04: Speed Demon** (Stage 4)

[image: Speed Demon]

This achievement appears to be awarded for completing the level under a certain time.  The exact length of time is not currently known.

---

**Secret Mission 05: Preferred Polarity** (Stage 5)

[image: Preferred Polarity]

I got this one by not killing any enemies in the first segment of the Top Secret Lab, but the icon seems to indicate that all you need to do is avoid killing any red ones.

---

**Secret Mission 06: Clean Shoes** (Stage 6)

[image: Clean Shoes]

Awarded for not landing on any of the membrane inside the Dragon

[image: Membrane]

---

**Secret Mission 07: Perfect Pacifist** (Stage 7)

[image: Perfect Pacifist]

Awarded for reaching the top of the Hall of Heroes without killing any enemies or taking damage

Comment: For the secret mission 4, I just rush quickly the level and get the achievement. So it's maybe that ^^

Comment: Ok i know how catch the speed demon achievement. You need to beat the bunny boss quickly, thats all =)

Comment: @Ophius How quickly?  I've taken her out pretty quickly already and it hasn't given it to me.  It could be for beating the entire level under a certain time though?  An actual number would be helpful.  Do you have a source?

Answer (score 2):

Secret Mission 04: Speed Demon.
Acquired by completing the level in a certain amount of time. Most easily done by setting the difficulty to Easy and rushing through the level, not stopping to fight.

Comment: Hi Sturm, and welcome to Arqade!  You can suggest edits to others answers to help improve them.  This is what you should have done for the existing answer.  Simply click the edit button, make your change, and experienced users will decide if the edit is appropriate or not.

Comment: Hiya.  Do you know what the amount of time is, specifically?